# На сколько нормально использовать в приложении два PDO объекта ?

Tags: php_pdo, php, оптимизация

Приветствую.
Так получилось что в приложении два готовых решения с github используют разные способы работы с одной и той же mysql базой данных.

Из одного компонента я могу получить PDO объект, он его вежливо отдает, а вторая либа поддерживает все возможные варианты соединения но просто передать туда уже готовый PDO объект нельзя. Вот и назревает вопрос, на сколько это вообще рационально использовать в приложении два различных соединения с бд ?

К слову, речь идет о либах RedbeanPHP и Illuminate/database

Comment: а форкнуть и дописать нужный код? а потом ещё и пулреквест сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Никто не запрещает использовать два разных коннекта к одной и той же базе из разных компонент приложения. Так же надо иметь в виду, что по завершению работы скрипта все соединения освобождаются, так что о "рациональности" тут нужно задумываться только если у вас офигилиарт одновременных сессий и скрипт работает по 10 минут.

Но если прям совсем не нравится держать два подключения вместо одного, то можно использовать "постоянные" соединения.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
));
```

Тогда при попытке создания новых подключений будет возвращаться уже существующее.